# What is wrong with my code? (adding numbers in an array)

Tags: assembly, mips

So, recent I have been taking assembly classes and one of them gave me an assignment. I coded everything except the last part... I just have to add the numbers in a given array and print the sum... easy right?
No, i have an error when i run it says that line 12 is out of range for some reason =/

So, here is my code:

```
.data

array: .word 1,2
size: .word 2
la $s0, array
lw $s1, size
li $t9, 0

.text

loop:
lw $a0, ($s0)
add $a0, $a0, $a0
addi $s0, $s0, 4
add $t9, $t9, 1
blt $t9, $s1, loop

li $v0, 1
syscall
```

Comment: which line is line 12?  `lw $a0, ($s0)`?  What exactly is the error message?  And what do you see when you run this in a debugger and look at register values?

Comment: @peter Cordes Error in C:\Users\Mohamad\Desktop\addingarray.asm line 13: Runtime exception at 0x00400004: address out of range 0x00000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`la $s0, array` is in the `.data` section, so it never executes.

If you'd used a debugger to single-step, you would have seen that your program never executes the instructions in the data section, and presumably starts execution at `loop:`.

At that point, `$s0` happens to still be zero (according to your error message).  Anyway, it's not pointing at `array`.

Comment: yes that worked great and i even noticed some logic errors and it now runs great thanks.
1 more thing... if i want to compare to strings do i just use beq bne? or is there more to it? im having some problems with my other program

Comment: i just wanna see if a word is in the array here is my code idk whats wrong tbh

`.data
array: .asciiz "one", "two", "three"
word: .asciiz "nine"
msgone: .asciiz "\nThe word is found"
msgtwo: .asciiz"\nThe word was not found"
size: .word 4

.text
la $s0, array
lw $s1, size
la $a1, word
li $t9, 0


loop:
beq $t9, $s1 , fail
la $a0, ($s0)
addi $s0, $s0, 4
add $t9,$t9, 1
beq $a1, $a0, found
bne $a1, $a0, loop




fail:
la $a0, msgtwo
li $v0, 4
syscall

found:
la $a0, msgone
li $v0, 4
syscall

j done

done:`

Comment: @MohammadAlBaba: If you entire string fits in a 32-bit register, yeah you could compare it with `beq`.  Otherwise not.  google for how to implement `strcmp` in asm.  **use a debugger**.  If you're using SPIM or MARS, there's probably one built-in.

Comment: i am using mars but my program always says that the string isnt contained in the array its making me a bit insane :P

Comment: @MohammadAlBaba: So single-step your code and look at what values are in registers.  Note that `.asciiz "one"` is 4 bytes, but `.asciiz "three"` is 6 bytes long.  So your "array" isn't an array anymore.  It's just some concatenated data with separately-labeled elements, separated by `0` bytes.

Comment: so how do i solve the issue? im still a beginner i literally just know a few functions

Comment: @MohammadAlBaba. You probably want to load a byte at a time from each string.  See http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html.  Try stuff that you thing might work and use the debugger to see what happens. 
 Like I said, google for how to compare strings in MIPS.  That's the same thing as implementing the C function `strcmp`.  If you get stuck with the debugger and can't figure out why your code is doing what it's doing, ask a separate question.